# Gitlab: pushes registering with repo, but pipelines not running and projects dashbaord 'last updated' is not changed

Tags: gitlab

When we push to our repository, we expect a pipeline to run. However, the pipelines have stopped starting automatically when we push.

In addition, when we try to start the pipeline manually, not all the tags and branches are showing in the dropdown list of tags and branches to choose from. When we browse the repository in Gitlab, we can see the branches and the pushed commits.

Finally, in the `/dashboard/projects` page, the 'last updated' date of the project is out of date, saying "yesterday" rather than "10 mins ago" (which is what shows when viewing the repository within the project.

We recently migrated server and so would expect that there is some migration issue going on here. Does anyone have any ideas where to look to solve this problem (i.e. what sub-systems could be not working/configured correctly to produce this behaviour)?

Gitlab version: 9.4.2

Run with Docker using: https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce/

**Update**

I tailed the logs while pushing to the repository, what follows is a chunk of logs around that time (starting with the SSH connection for the push). Potentially the 404 around prometheus is interesting, but I'm not sure that's unexpected (we're not using it):

```
==> /var/log/gitlab/sshd/current <==
2017-08-01_17:05:16.86559 Accepted publickey for git from (removed) port 57680 ssh2: RSA SHA256:(removed)

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log <==
Started POST "/api/v4/internal/allowed" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-01 17:05:17 +0000

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-shell/gitlab-shell.log <==
I, [2017-08-01T17:05:17.088866 #2286]  INFO -- : POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v4/internal/allowed 0.01170
I, [2017-08-01T17:05:17.089030 #2286]  INFO -- : gitlab-shell: executing git command <git-receive-pack /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/products/preside-ext-ems.git> for user with key key-2.

==> /var/log/gitlab/sshd/current <==
2017-08-01_17:05:17.20480 Received disconnect from x.x.x.x port 57680:11: disconnected by user
2017-08-01_17:05:17.20483 Disconnected from x.x.x.x port 57680

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log <==
Started GET "/-/metrics" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-01 17:05:18 +0000
Processing by MetricsController#index as HTML
Filter chain halted as :validate_prometheus_metrics rendered or redirected
Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started POST "/api/v4/jobs/request" for 172.17.0.1 at 2017-08-01 17:05:18 +0000

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/current <==
2017-08-01_17:05:18.16504 gitlab.mycompany.com @ - - [2017-08-01 17:05:18.158505651 +0000 UTC] "POST /api/v4/jobs/request HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "" "gitlab-ci-multi-runner 9.4.1 (9-4-stable; go1.8.3; linux/amd64)" 0.006484

==> /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log <==
172.17.0.1 - - [01/Aug/2017:17:05:18 +0000] "POST /api/v4/jobs/request HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "-" "gitlab-ci-multi-runner 9.4.1 (9-4-stable; go1.8.3; linux/amd64)"

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log <==
Started POST "/api/v4/jobs/request" for 172.17.0.1 at 2017-08-01 17:05:23 +0000

==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/current <==
2017-08-01_17:05:23.16534 gitlab.mycompany.com @ - - [2017-08-01 17:05:23.159064793 +0000 UTC] "POST /api/v4/jobs/request HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "" "gitlab-ci-multi-runner 9.4.1 (9-4-stable; go1.8.3; linux/amd64)" 0.006235

==> /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log <==
172.17.0.1 - - [01/Aug/2017:17:05:23 +0000] "POST /api/v4/jobs/request HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "-" "gitlab-ci-multi-runner 9.4.1 (9-4-stable; go1.8.3; linux/amd64)"
```

Comment: You need to look in the gitlab logs for errors.

Comment: Yup - haven't managed to find any errors in the many log files that there are.

Comment: Gitlab is running using docker or a normal system?

Comment: Yes, with docker.

Comment: Usually in that case I would do this have one terminal open `docker logs -f <containerid>` Then at off time with least possible traffic, execute the workflow and capture the logs from screen to text file and analyze. Else for a running gitlab server there are just too many logs

Comment: Yes, exactly - thankfully its a pretty quiet server but even so, lots of logs! I'm currently trying a restore of a backup (just copied all the data + conf directories over before). If still a problem after that, I'll try looking more closely at the logs.

Comment: logs added to op

Comment: Just one 404, Started GET "/-/metrics" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-01 17:05:18 +0000
Processing by MetricsController#index as HTML
Filter chain halted as :validate_prometheus_metrics rendered or redirected. Which I am not sure is one with impact or not. Open an issue on gitlab project with these logs and see what they say. This is no more of an issue related docker or anything. It is gitlab

Answer (score 0):

Not **exactly** an answer - but I have wiped out the server and rebuilt from scratch. Manually recreating each project and importing the repositories for each project.

A royal PITA, **but** everything is working as expected.

I can only guess that either something was setup on the host server that was causing issues (I did a clean install on the host to start again), or that there was something about simply copying over all our configuration and data dirs from the old server to the new server that caused issues (seems unlikely).

Not much help I'm afraid :(